# Having trouble getting react and flask to talk to each other

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, fetch

I have two service running on the same machine:

1. React front end served directly by nginx
2. A flask server (on port 5000) running on localhost.

As you'd imagine, the react app used fetch to call the flask server to do the heavy lifting. However, I can't seem to get fetch to hit the end point.

I've wrapped the flask endpoing in `CORS(app)` to eliminate that as the issue. I've also tried multiple ways of feeding `fetch` the endpoint (http, https, localhost), all to no avail. What the heck is going on? As it stands now, I am getting a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` upon the request (but I can't see the endpoint isn't getting hit). Here are the crucial pieces of my code, as it stands now:

Flask:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
@app.route('/api/get_dashboard_art', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def hello():
    return jsonify({'data': 'stuff'})
```

React/fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/get_dashboard_art')
    .then(function (response_json) {
        return response_json.json()
    })
```

Another thing to note, I can do a `curl localhost:5000/api/*` and receive all the information I need. So I know the service is running.

I've seen quite a bit of chatter from people having similar issues, but I really haven't found any resolve. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... the link that @diypcjourney posted got me thinking about a few things. What I ended up doing was putting a proxy within my react nginx config. It took all the calls from the FE and directs them to the flask app. Here is what it looks like (again, this is the react nginx config, not the the flask one)

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;  # or whatever your IP/site is

  root /var/www/reactapp/build/;

  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/;
  }
}
```

Here is the nginx docs: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

I'm not sure if this is solves what the problem is, but it seems like a decent solution. I would love someone to explain better why this works.

Answer (score 0):

In your react code,

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/get_dashboard_art')
```

You are calling the endpoint (/api/get_dashboard_art) **NOT** (/) like you have in your flask app.

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

change the endpoint to

```
@app.route('/api/get_dashboard_art', methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

and it should work.

Comment: This is a typo on my end. The flask endpoint is correct. Sorry. Fixing now.

Comment: try adding a line with request.method == 'GET' or request.method == 'POST' and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: As in specify the flask endpoint to only be one options? so: `@app.route('/api/get_dashboard_art', methods="GET")` ?

Comment: Also another problem I had with flask was that my localhost port 5000 is usually taken up (I'm on mac) so try configuring the port to 1234 or some random number because it seems like a network issue.

Comment: I've tried multiple ports, to no avail. Tried different request methods as well. the fact that I can `curl` to flask but cant fetch is what is really confusing.

Comment: Check out this link. https://serverfault.com/questions/749503/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-reset